# How do I make carrierwave create versions conditionally?

Tags: carrierwave

[This](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Do-conditional-processing) doesn't actually work. The version doesn't get processed but versions[:thumb] still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb#L163), the `:if` option is only referenced in `version_exists?`.  Which means that `versions[:thumb]` returns a version but `version_exists?(:thumb)` returns false.

It doesn't make sense to me but that's how it appears to work.